Option for a custom TikZ command which can be set to one of three values
Related:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730199/319072
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730112/319072

I am trying to make an option for a custom tikz command which can be set to one of three values. Then, based on which value is chosen (or, the default if none is chosen) we will execute certain code.
For example, I would like to do this with some custom line endings I made. However, the following code doesn't work. I did get help from AI to make it.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{
  ends/.is choice,
  ends/neither/.code={\def\tikz@ends{neither}},
  ends/behind/.code={\def\tikz@ends{behind}},
  ends/front/.code={\def\tikz@ends{front}},
  ends/both/.code={\def\tikz@ends{both}},
  ends/.default=behind
}

%radius for dots
\newcommand{\myR}{0.1}

% Draw a dot at a position
\newcommand{\myDot}[2][]{
  \begingroup
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
  \coordinate (DeliberatelyLongName) at (#2);
  \fill[#1] (DeliberatelyLongName) circle[radius=\myR];
  \endgroup
}

% Draw an arrow with custom ends
\newcommand{\myArrow}[3][]{
  \begingroup
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
  
  \ifx\tikz@ends\neither
      \draw[->, #1] 
      (#2) -- ++(#3);
  \else
      \ifx\tikz@ends\behind
          \myDot{#2}
          \draw[->, shorten <=\myR cm, #1] 
          (#2) -- ++(#3);
      \fi
      \ifx\tikz@ends\front
          \draw[->, shorten >=\myR cm, #1]
          (#2) -- ++(#3) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName);
          \myDot{DeliberatelyLongName}
      \fi
      \ifx\tikz@ends\both
          \myDot{#2}
          \draw[thick, ->, shorten <=\myR cm, shorten >=\myR cm, #1]
          (#2) -- ++(#3) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName);
          \myDot{DeliberatelyLongName}
      \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myArrow[ends=neither]{0,0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=behind]{3,0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=front]{0,3}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=both]{0,-3}{2,2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Just in case, if it isn't clear: ends/.default doesn't set the style that will be set if none is chosen, it's the one that is set if you use the ends key without a value.

Do you want a circle as a tip of your path? Do you really want a circle in the xyz coordinate system? (0.1cm and 0.1 are different lengths.) Can you show what you're trying to achieve with your code?

@Qrrbrbirlbel (#1) Good to know! (#2) Really, I thought the default measurement was cm, so 0.1 would be 0.1cm. (#3) I want a line segment between two circles, shortened by their radius on both ends - I'll post a pic.

#2 It is, the keys x, y and z control this. If you scale the xyz  control system (by using these keys) or the canvas coordinate system (by using scale et al) you will also change how 0.1 and 0.1cm will be interpreted. A node, usually will not scale with either (but that can be changed), neither does an arrow tip.

Make your styles do the work. Let ends set the proper shorten amount itself. Using two keys possible dot < and possible dot > a node will be placed if it is needed.
That said, it looks like you want a circle as an arrow tip. This is what Code B does.
Code A
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{
  ends size/.initial=.1cm,
  ends/.is choice,
  ends/neither/.style={
    shorten <=+ 0pt, shorten >=+ 0pt,
    possible dot </.code=, possible dot >/.code=},
  ends/behind/.style={
    shorten <=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size}, shorten >=+ 0pt,
    possible dot </.style=@possible dot, possible dot >/.code=},
  ends/front/.style={
    shorten <=+ 0pt, shorten >=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size},
    possible dot </.code=, possible dot >/.style=@possible dot},
  ends/both/.style={
    shorten <=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size}, shorten >=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size},
    possible dot </.style=@possible dot, possible dot >/.style=@possible dot},
  every my arrow/.style={->, ends=behind}, % this is a default style for your arrow
  @possible dot/.style={insert path={node[shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size={2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}]{}}}
}
% Draw an arrow with custom ends
\newcommand{\myArrow}[3][]{\draw[{every my arrow,#1}] (#2) [possible dot <] -- ++(#3) [possible dot >];}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,-3) grid (5,5);
\myArrow[ends=neither]{0, 0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=behind] {3, 0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=front]  {0, 3}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=both]   {0,-3}{2,2}
\myArrow[red]         {0, 1}{2,2} % uses ends=behind
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Code B
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{
  ends size/.initial=.1cm,
  ends/.is choice,
  ends/neither/.style={arrows=->},
  ends/behind/.style ={arrows={   Circle[length={2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}, sep={-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}]->}},
  ends/front/.style  ={arrows={-> Circle[length={2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}, sep={-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}]}},
  ends/both/.style   ={arrows={   Circle[length={2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}, sep={-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}]-
                                > Circle[length={2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}, sep={-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ends size})}]}},
  every my arrow/.style=ends/behind
}

% Draw an arrow with custom ends
\newcommand{\myArrow}[3][]{\draw[{every my arrow,#1}] (#2) -- ++(#3);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ends size=.1cm]
\draw[help lines] (0,-3) grid (5,5);
\myArrow[ends=neither]{0, 0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=behind] {3, 0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=front]  {0, 3}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=both]   {0,-3}{2,2}
\myArrow[red]         {0, 1}{2,2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


You have to rework your checks, your \ifx can't work this way.
The following defines a pretty basic compare test for this.
Also you shouldn't define your own macros starting with \tikz@.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{
  ends/.is choice,
  ends/neither/.code={\def\jasper@ends{neither}},
  ends/behind/.code={\def\jasper@ends{behind}},
  ends/front/.code={\def\jasper@ends{front}},
  ends/both/.code={\def\jasper@ends{both}},
  ends=behind
}

%radius for dots
\newcommand{\myR}{0.1}

% Draw a dot at a position
\newcommand{\myDot}[2][]{
  \begingroup
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
  \coordinate (DeliberatelyLongName) at (#2);
  \fill[#1] (DeliberatelyLongName) circle[radius=\myR];
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\jasperIf[2]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \def\tmp{#2}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx#1\tmp
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }

% Draw an arrow with custom ends
\newcommand{\myArrow}[3][]{
  \begingroup
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
  
  \jasperIf\jasper@ends{neither}
    {%
      \draw[->, #1] 
      (#2) -- ++(#3);
    }
    {}%
  \jasperIf\jasper@ends{behind}
    {%
      \myDot{#2}
      \draw[->, shorten <=\myR cm, #1] 
      (#2) -- ++(#3);
    }
    {}%
  \jasperIf\jasper@ends{front}
    {%
      \draw[->, shorten >=\myR cm, #1]
      (#2) -- ++(#3) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName);
      \myDot{DeliberatelyLongName}
    }
    {}%
  \jasperIf\jasper@ends{both}
    {%
      \myDot{#2}
      \draw[thick, ->, shorten <=\myR cm, shorten >=\myR cm, #1]
      (#2) -- ++(#3) coordinate(DeliberatelyLongName);
      \myDot{DeliberatelyLongName}
    }
    {}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myArrow[ends=neither]{0,0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=behind]{3,0}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=front]{0,3}{2,2}
\myArrow[ends=both]{0,-3}{2,2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I appreciate your advice, and all the help you've given me over these past several posts. I decided to give the tick to Qrrbrbirlbel here, but still, definitely +1.

@Jasper that's totally fine, they know much more about TikZ than I, I'm just someone who can code in TeX :)
